# How to remove an object from NSFetchRequest sortDescriptors NSArray

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios5

i want to traverse through sortDescriptors NSArray and remove an object that doesn't meet a certain criteria. Can someone here please show me how can i do this correctly.

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@“CarsInventory”];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@“model” ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

for (CarsInventory* carInfo in request.sortDescriptors)
{
        if (![self isCarWithin5FileRadius:carInfo.location])
        {
            [request.sortDescriptors delete: bookInfo]; // CRASH         
        }
}
```

Comment: the array `request.sortDescriptors`doesn't hold your fetched data but only the sort descriptor you added to it. You need to fetch data first into a new array and iterate over that array. You will need a `NSMutableArray if you want to delete objects. But you have to delete them from your store, not from the fetch array!

Comment: Volker: thanks, i dont want to delete them from the store, just want take remove some objects that dont meet criteria from request.sortDescriptors, then load it into NSFetchedResultsController by using initWithFetchRequest:request. Can i just assign the NSMutableArray back to request.sortDescriptors after deleting object?

Comment: You can't really do this with an `NSFetchedResultsController` as this predicate can not be translated into a `SQL` statement

Comment: Use predicates in your fetch request to filter data.  Use sort descriptors to order the results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two problems here:

- `NSArray` is not mutable, hence you cannot remove items from it. You should convert it to `NSMutableArray`.
- you should not remove items from an array during enumeration. You can iterate through the array using `for(int i=0;i<[yourArray count];i++)`, however.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@“CarsInventory”];
NSArray *sortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@“model” ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

NSMutableArray *mutArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sortedArray count]];

for (CarsInventory* carInfo in sortedArray)
{
    if ([self isCarWithin5FileRadius:carInfo.location])
    {
        [mutArray addObject:carInfo];// add it to mutable array
    }

}

NSLog(@"New Mut Array--%@",mutArray); //log the final list
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify an array whilst it is being iterated with NSFastEnumeration - this will almost certainly crash or cause awkward bugs

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? It doesn't even make sense - `request.sortDescriptors` returns an array of `NSSortDescriptor` objects not `CarsInventory` objects - therefore this should just crash as `NSSortDescriptor` does not respond to `isCarWithin5FileRadius:`

Comment: @Paul.s  check it again. i have modified it after testing.  Thanks